# Convert a string to a float in java

Tags: java, string, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java : convert float to String and String to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552660/java-convert-float-to-string-and-string-to-float)

I'm extracting some numbers from a string, these are being stored as another string. Is there a way to convert these strings into a float?

i tried float f = "string"; but this didnt work.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552660/java-convert-float-to-string-and-string-to-float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Float.parseFloat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) but it does throw a [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) if it fails so this is one time I would recommend catching it.

```
try {
    Float.parseFloat("0.4")
} catch (NumberFormatException e){ 
  //input is not a float
}
```

If you want more precision then look at [Double.parseDouble()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) or even the [BigDecimal string constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`Float.parseFloat()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

This way---:   Float.parseFloat("0.4");