# java equivalent of atof C++

Tags: java, c++

I want to convert a c++ (opencv)  method to java (jaavcv)  method

I'm worrying about this line . Is the conversion correct?

```
 float label=atof(entryPath.filename().c_str());

 --> float label=Float.parseFloat(child.getName());
```

Comment: If child.getName() will have string value which can be converted to float as it it then this is correct.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552660/java-convert-float-to-string-and-string-to-float

Comment: Note, however, that this may throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ,You are on track

```
float label = Float.parseFloat(child.getName());
```

where  `child.getName()`  is `string` and in **valid float format**

If you want it back

```
String floToStr= Float.toString(label );
```

Update:

If you check [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29),

That method **parseFloat**

> Returns a new float initialized to the value represented by the specified String, as performed by the valueOf method of class Float.

```
Throws:
NullPointerException - if the string is null
NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable float.
```

Comment: For example :`suresh` is not a valid float value :)

Comment: valid float format is .5, 0.5, 1.5, 23.56233, and i think 1.4582e14 so normal notation, notation without the leading zero if there is one and scientific notation

Answer (score 0):

If `child.getName()` returns well-formatted String (for example `1.5`) then yes, it's correct.

```
float label = Float.parseFloat(child.getName());
```

If `child.getName()` doesn't return parsable float (for example `1,5`), `parseFloat()` will throw `NumberFormatException`.