# Turning string into float Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am new to Java so this may be a simple question.

I have made a calculator where the user clicks buttons and it enters the text into a `JTextField`.

I have used the `.getText()` method and saved it into a `String`.

Using `System.out.println()` I have seen that the `String` is "8*7*7-8/4", obviously if I could just execute this and get the answer 390 then this would be far easier than splitting it up and making it more complicated than it seems.

Thanks Matt

Comment: You could use a stack to convert infix to postfix to get the correct order of operations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7552675/2282538

Comment: String to float: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552660/java-convert-float-to-string-and-string-to-float

Comment: One possible way to use javascript like eval. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2605051/1193808

Answer (score 1):

You can actually evaluate the expression `"8*7*7-8/4"` directly using the built-in Java script engine. Have a look at [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

Also have a look at [this codereview post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42323/math-expression-solver) that explains some good points on how to evaluate a math expression present in a string.

Comment: I am referring to the `javax.script.ScriptEngineManager` and `javax.script.ScriptEngine` classes as shown in the link to the post I have given. Its built-in in JDK 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to get the value of a float from a string:

```
Float.valueOf(string);
```

So you could do this, whenever a user inputs a number:

```
//method when user inputs a number, the String input will be what the user adds
float number = Float.valueOf(input);
```

Also, you could do something like this:

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String input = "40+2";
System.out.println(engine.eval(input));
```

Above code from: [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

Comment: Hi I tried this and I got 

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3*6"

Comment: @user3494178 The first code, `Float.valueOf(string);`, only works if your doing a single number, like `5.6`, or `8`. Stuff like `8 + 3` and `5.6 * 22.1` won't work here. Yet, the bottom code, with`ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();` will evaluate expressions like `3 * 6`, or `8 + 5` for you

Answer (score 0):

Add jar file jav8-jsr223-win-amd64-0.6 to the classpath for Java8 or corresponding jar as per JDK version and write the below code

```
String val = "8*7*7-8/4";//make it to get from field.getText()

ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
Object result = engine.eval(val);

System.out.println(result);
```