# Java format all floats into a string

Tags: java, string, format

Here is my code:

```
float e[10]=new float[10];
```

Is there any way to format all the 10 floats into a format string? Maybe something like this in Python:

```
a=range(10)
print ('#'+'(%f)'*10+'#')%tuple(a)
```

Is there a method like this in java? I mean getting a string like "#(1.0)(2.0)(3.0)#" for the case of array_size 3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java : convert float to String and String to float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552660/java-convert-float-to-string-and-string-to-float)

Comment: Not possible in one go! in JAVA

Comment: What is your question?  How to format float values into a string or how to get 10 of them into one string?

Comment: @AleksG get all 10 of them into one format string.

Comment: @VD' No way to do this in java?

Comment: @Alaeddine I want to format all of them into one string. It's not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float e[10]=new float[10];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e));
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

Try this , make a loop to the end of the array and `parseFloat` to a String `msg`

```
 String msg = "";
 float[] e= new float[10];
 for(int i=0;i<e.length();i++){
    msg = msg + Float.parseFloat(e[i]);
 }
```