# Can i convert String to float coming from server?

Tags: java, android, sockets, client, server

I want to change a float coming from server to string or string to float.
Can i convert string to float coming from server?

```
    String coming;
    coming = new String(rec.getData());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),comnig,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: `String coming = String.valueOf(rec.getData());` perhaps? A `float` is a `float`, regardless of where you got it from...

Comment: Please search before asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can convert a String to a float.
Simply do:

```
Float.parseFloat(string);
```

You may want to surround this with a try and catch because if the string is not compatible with type float it will create a stack-trace.

Answer (score 0):

check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552675/2329972

converting string to float

`float f = Float.parseFloat(coming);`

it's better to use try -catch , because your coming value may contain something that are not compatible with float type .