# Working with numbers in android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development. I am creating an app in which attendance percentage needs to be calculated. I want to calculate the attendance percentage and place that data in the EDIT TEXT field but when I run the application the data is not calculated instead I have to insert it manually. Please help me out with this. TIA :)
Here is my code

```
float percentage = ((attendClasses / totClasses) * 100);
                        str_percentage = String.valueOf(percentage);
                        ed_percentage.setText(str_percentage);

                        // To insert candidate values into the database
                        boolean result = mySQLiteAdapter.onInsertAttendance(
                                studId, subjId, str_totclasses,
                                str_attendedclasses, str_percentage);
```

Comment: Why aren't you able to do so?

Comment: Please first explain what exactly the problem is, otherwise no one can help you...

Comment: I want the percentage to be calculated and placed in edit text field but the percentage is not showing when I am running the app

Comment: So, you aren't able to set the EditText text?

Comment: I am able to see the EditText but there I need to insert value manually. I want it to be calculated and placed in that field

Comment: Which value you are getting now? 0?

Comment: Yes. I am getting 0.0

Comment: If totClasses is an int, cast it to float '(float)totClasses'

Comment: If `attendClasses` and `totClasses` are `int`s, then Java integer division will give you zero when you divide them, assuming `attendClasses` is smaller than `totClasses`.

Comment: integers don't take the floating part in account.

Comment: @user3530830 'is not showing' is very different from 'is 0.0', don't you think? You could have a correct answer within minutes, if you had explained this correctly. Please be careful the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `float percentage = ((attendClasses / totClasses) * 100)`; to  `float percentage = ((attendClasses*100) / totClasses);`

Here Your `attendClasses`  and `totClasses` are int value.
So division of two int value `attendClasses/totClasses`  will result into 0. As here 
`totClasses>attendClasses`.

Comment: I tried as u said but the percentage is getting calculated after I click in add percentage and precision values are getting ignored

Comment: You need to cast result in float like float percentage = (float)(attendClasses*100) / totClasses; for precision values.

Answer (score -1):

try using `Float.toString(percentage);` instead of `String.valueOf(percentage);`

Comment: percentage is a primitive type.

Comment: `float f = Float.parseFloat("25");
String s = Float.toString(25.0f);`   check this for reference  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552660/java-convert-float-to-string-and-string-to-float