# How to change a float into a String in Java?

Tags: java, rounding

Is it possible to change a float value to a String? If possible, is it also possible to converting it to a String while rounding the number to the nearest integer?

For example if I have a float such as 2.335 then, can I change it to a String of value "2.335" or "2" (by rounding it)?

Comment: Should `2.8` become 2 or 3 (I am assuming 3 but just want to make sure)?

Comment: use `String.valueOf` method

Comment: Please search the site before asking questions. Your question is nicely answered by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552660/java-convert-float-to-string-and-string-to-float?rq=1) question and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java) one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use java `Float` class:

```
String s = Float.toString(25.0f);
```

if you want to round down a number, simply use the `Math.floor()` function.

```
float f = 2.9999f;
String s = Float.toString(Math.floor(f));//rounds the number to 2 and converts to String
```

first line rounds the number down to the nearest integer and the second line converts it to a string.

Another way of doing this is using the `String.valueOf(floatNumber);`

```
float amount=100.00f;
String strAmount=String.valueOf(amount);
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can simply do

```
float example = 2.335
String s = String.valueOf(Math.round(example));
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a float to a String:

```
String s = Float.toString(2.335f);
```

Rounding can be done via

```
String.format("%.5g%n", 0.912385);
```

which returns 0.91239

For a more elaborate answer, see [Round a number in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

Your first requirement can be fullfilled with `String.valueOf`

```
float f = 1.6f;
String str = String.valueOf(f);
```

For roundoff you can use `Math.round` **and not** `Math.floor`. As `Math.floor` will convert 1.6 to 1.0 and not 2.0 while `Math.round` will roundoff your number to nearest integer.