# Java Int to Float to get 1f for 1

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How to convert an `Integer` or a `String` number to a `float` number like this `"1"` to `1.0f` (or `1f`). I tried most of all codes, but all time I get the same. But, I need to get `1f`.

```
val num = 1
val b = num.toFloat()
Log.i("b",b.toString())
```

Result is `1.0`.

Comment: Do you need the trailing 'f'?

Comment: Isn't `1.0` exactly what you want? `b` is a float.

Comment: `System.out.println (b +"f");`

Answer (score 1):

By adding `toFloat()` to `num`, you have converted `num` to from an `int` to `float`. Kotlin also allows you to convert to float using conventional notation that is by adding `f` or `F` at the end of `1`

```
val num = 1f
```

or

```
val num = 1F
```

To print out the float with the trailing 'f', you can convert the float to a string and add a "f".

```
val num = 1F
print(num.toString() + "f") // Result = 1.0f
```

To print out just 1f, you don't need to convert it to a float.

```
val num = 1
print(num.toString() + "f")
```

Answer (score -4):

You can find your answer here: [convert float to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552660/java-convert-float-to-string-and-string-to-float).

```
float f = Float.parseFloat("1");
```

This case works for a string. For ints, cast the value:

```
int val = 1;
float f = (float) val;
```

Comment: @ChristianBrüggemann My bad.. I didn't pay attention and I don't know this language. But it does clearly say in the title and in the tags "Java", which is what confused me